# Finding the last X-axis value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I am interested in finding the final value of the x-axis  for this graph.

[[image: MATLAB Plot[1]]

I've tried using the Xlim command to obtain the range of values along the x-axis, but it gave me the range of the entire graph ([0 250000]) rather than the final value of the graph, located around ~22000 Hz. Is there a function in MATLAB that can find this value for me?

Comment: your question needs clarification. What does "final value" mean?

Comment: I'm trying to find where the blue line along the x-axis ends. Based on pure observation, it looks as though it ends around 22000 (~2.2 x 10^5 according to the graph), but I want to know the exact value. Not too sure how to do this through MATLAB

Comment: you still don't say how your data gets into your plot.

Comment: from what this looks like, you simply forgot to realize that this might simply be the length of your vector

Comment: The data comes from an encoded audio file. I took the fft of the signal and eliminated the other half. After taking the length of the signal, I get 441000. The carrier frequency is 11416, and the sampling rate Fs = 44100. I'm attempting to find the last value of the x-axis here so that I know what frequency I should use in order to demodulate the audio file.

Aaaaaaand I just realized that I am an idiot. Thank you for your help Marcus, everything is suddenly crystal clear

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your x-values are in the variable 'x' just do:

```
max(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to obtain that value *from the graph*, that is, you don't have access to the variables that originated the graph.

Get the `'XData'` and `'YData'` of the plotted curve, and then look for the point with greatest *x* value:

```
ch = get(gca, 'Children'); %// all children of current axes
ch = findobj(ch, 'type', 'line'); %// keep only line objects
xData = get(ch(1), 'XData'); %// take first line object, if there are more than one
yData = get(ch(1), 'YData');
[resultX, ind] = max(xData); %// resultX is the greatest x value in the graph
resultY = yData(ind); %// resultY is the corresponding y value
```

Comment: or max(ch(1).XData) in MATLAB 2014b or newer